# What does convergence of a Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence say about the homotopy type of the totalization?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences, koszul-duality

Given a cosimplicial space or spectrum $X^\bullet$, there is an associated Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence. This starts out as the bigraded object obtained by taking homotopy groups of each $X^n$ and then taking cohomology of the associated cochain complex (where one may have issues in low degrees if $X^\bullet$ is a cosimplicial space because of non-abelian homotopy groups).

One particularly well studied example of this is the Eilenberg-Moore Spectral sequence obtained from a fiber square. There, we have a cospan $X\to Z\leftarrow Y$ with homotopy pullback $W$. Noticing that the cospan gives $X$ and $Y$ the structure of $Z$-comodules we can build the two-sided cobar construction $C^\bullet(X,Z,Y)$ which is a cosimplicial space with $X\times Z^n \times Y$ in degree $n$ (where the coface maps are given by $X\overset{\Delta}\to X\times X\to X\times Z$, $Y\overset{\Delta}\to Y\times Y\to Y\times Z$ and $Z\overset{\Delta}\to Z\times Z$). The associated BKSS of this cosimplicial space is supposed to give us information then about $W$.

Bousfield has given many conditions that ensure strong convergence of the associated Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence. For instance, for the EMSS described above, if $Z$ is simply connected, the Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence converges strongly.

My questions are the following:

- If the BKSS of a cosimplicial space/spectrum converges strongly, does that mean that the thing it converges to is indeed the homotopy type of the limit of that cosimplicial diagram?
- Is the limit of the cobar construction defining the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence always equivalent to the homotopy pullback of that cospan?
- Consider the following example: there is a coaction of $BO$ on $MO$ coming from the Thom diagonal. As such we can consider the cosimplicial spectrum $C^\bullet(MO,\mathbb{S}[BO],\mathbb{S})$ where $\mathbb{S}$ has the trivial $BO$-coaction. The associated spectral sequence is the $MO$-Adams-Novikov spectral sequence and converges to the homotopy of the 2-completed sphere spectrum. Does that mean that the totalization of that cosimplicial object is equivalent to the 2-completed sphere spectrum, or is that just saying that this is all the spectral sequence can see of it?

This last is ultimately a question about Koszul duality. There should be an adjunction between "spectra with an $O$-action" and "spectra with a $BO$-coaction." Constructing $MO$ from the sphere spectrum should be the left adjoint of this equivalence, and I'd like to think that taking a "cotensor product" should be the way of going back. However, it's not clear to me how to check that $\mathbb{S}$ can be recovered in this way from $MO$.

Comment: Sorry if this is a naive question but what filtered group are you thinking of when you say that the BK spectral sequence converges strongly?

Comment: Coming back to this I think it's actually kind of straightforward. Given the right sorts of fibrant replacements, that totalization will definitely be the homotopy pullback (in the case of spaces). The question about the BKSS is whether or not it correctly computes the homotopy or homology groups of that space.

Comment: I think that there are results about this in Brooke Shipley's PhD thesis, although I don't remember the details.